# FindViewByID in Xamarin.Android is not recognizing the ID defined in the ..axml

Tags: xamarin.android, findviewbyid

I am new to Xamarin. I have created EditText item in Content_main.xaml. Source code for EditText is below

```
<EditText
    android:id = "@+id/inputBill"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

In the main CS file, I am trying to get the value from EditText element via its ID. Sample Code below

```
    EditText inputBill1;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Content_main);
        inputBill1 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.inputBill);
```

Getting below error
"'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'inputBill'"

Please let me know If i am missing any thing.

Comment: Honestly sometimes it's just because the resource file hasn't updated globally, you can do a few things to try and nudge this to work, you could try changing the ID name to something slightly different, or closing and re-opening Visual Studio. Honestly it's that daft.

Comment: please add your axml code. so i can help out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Make that the Resource is your namespace.Resource

**2.** Ignore the error message of VS, continue to build (it's vs tools's problem,always notice id can not find, but you can still run)

**3.** If still not work after the above two points, delete the content inside the  "Resources/Resource.Designer.cs" file, and then rebuild (delete the contents of the file, not delete the file)

Comment: Thanks for the response. It was still showing error but when I run the application, it ran successfully.